# log all mysql errors to a database or sort off?

Tags: php, mysql, database, error-handling

This is exactly what I need:

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $buser, $pwd, $db);

$query = $conn->query("mysql_query here");

if (!query) {
    $error = $conn->error;
    $log_error = $conn->query("INSERT INTO tab (log) VALUES ('$error')");
}
?>
```

However, this does not work, the error is not being submitted into the db.

For how much it actually is bad to use a database to log errors, seems the only way to accomplish my needs.

What is needed: I need to log all errors from queries, no matter of the type, and log them somewhere which can be viewed on a private webpage accessible just for a specified level account with PHP just to display all those errors.

I already have everything working, account levels etc, just it seems can't find a way to log past occured errors on a php page in the following format:

```
account_who_caused_error || page_where_error_occured.php || error_message || datetime
```

error_log cannot be used due to the nature of what i need. so what exactly remains to do that?

Comment: What type of object is `$conn`?

Comment: $conn is a simple connection to database: $conn = mysqli_connect($webserver, $webuser, $webpwd, $webdb);

Comment: It seems a bad idea to log database errors in the database :-) If you need to view the log via a webpage you can still just log the errors in a text file and make that file accessible, or you could store them in a json file or CSV if the data structures are more complex.

Comment: have you tried escaping the `$error` variable?  `$log_error = $conn->query("INSERT INTO tab (log) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string($error) . "')");`

Comment: Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible that the `$error` variable contains a single quote and thus is causing the query to be malformed. Escaping the `$error` variable may help:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($server, $buser, $pwd, $db);

$query = $conn->query("mysql_query here");

if (!query) {
    $error = $conn->error;
    $log_error = $conn->query("INSERT INTO tab (log) VALUES ('" . mysqli_real_escape_string ($error) . "')");
}
```

As has been mentioned in the comments above, logging database errors in a database could be self-defeating. If your database has problems, no errors will be logged.

Comment: in such case, if you know, how i can save the error logs in a file and then make it accessible them on a php page, but, formatted in a table for 1 error line = 1 row, and datas formatted in columns? like error type, message, datetime and so on? Is it possible?

Comment: You could use `fputcsv` which will output into a CSV formatted file. That could then be read again using `fgetcsv`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php